# cordova:how to close page in cordova?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a page included button close.

When I click on this button it should close the page in Cordova

I tried `window.close` but it didn't close the page

and install InAppBrowser  plugin

Comment: you want to close the app or close page

Comment: close page not close app

Answer (score 0):

I use a workaround... Since the inAppBrowser can be closed only with the back button or trough javascript. I display a close button from serverside that will change the current url firing also the event 'loadstop' letting to use the .close() method, in this way only the child browser will be closed, your app will remain in the same state.

**Add in html** .

`<a href="/mobile/close">Close</a>`

**Add in script**.

```
var ref = window.open(encodeURI(url), '_blank', options);
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {        
    if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
        ref.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: close page not close app

Answer (score 0):

The pages are not handled by Cordova. Cordova recommends you use Single Page Application frameworks, such as Angular, Vue, Ionic, or Framework7. These frameworks will handle how pages are closed.